# Unable to locate adb, android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, adb, android-virtual-device

I want to run  Android Virtual Device in android studio, I have installed "Android SDK platform tools", and `adb.exe` is there, but when I run appears:

1. `Unable to locate adb, android studio`
2. then, `The ADB binary found at C: \Users\Lenovo\Appdata\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe is obsolete and has seriousperformance problems with the Android Emulator. Please update to a newer version to get significantly faster app/file transfer`

**How can solve this problem with adb, and how to update to newer version?**

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded platform-tools from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools). It works fine for me with the latest android studio. Steps I followed:

1. Download platform-tools
2. Copy and paste the downloaded folder in SDK
3. Add SDK/platform-tools/ to the system path.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the SDK location from File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK

[image]

After downloading/updating required files, select the AVD icon and setup the Virtual Device. That should work.